# Sitecore 9.3 SIA Prerequisites Installation Fails

Tags: sitecore-install-assistant

After completing some of the [initial developer environment setup](https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/blog/359/installing-sitecore-9-prerequisites-4524), I downloaded the Sitecore 9.3 "Graphical setup package for XP Single" from [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/93/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_93_Initial_Release.aspx). I ran the .exe, and while attempting to install the prerequisites I saw this error (0x800f0954):

[image: Sitecore Installation Assistant prerequisite download failure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading up to this installation, I recalled that I had some trouble getting previous prerequisites installed; specifically those mentioned [here](https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/blog/359/installing-sitecore-9-prerequisites-4524).

Even more specifically:

- Adding IIS via “Add / Remove Features” dialog
- Installing Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers (Use Web Platform Installer to install)

It turns out that due to a group policy setting on my machine, installation of .NET 3.5 was failing.

The fix is outlined [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/112308/error-code-0x800f0954-on-windows-10.html):

> Temporarily bypass WSUS server using the following registry edit (requires administrator privileges).
>
> 1. Right-click Start, and click Run
> 2. Type regedit.exe and click OK
> 3. Go to the following registry key:
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
> 4. In the right-pane, if the value named UseWUServer exists, set its data to 0
> 5. Exit the Registry Editor
> 6. Restart the Windows Update service or restart the PC.

After performing these actions I was able to install everything necessary without any more errors.